# Can I determine what changed in an upgraded package using apt or dpkg on Debian 6?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, dpkg

I just did an `apt-get upgrade` on my Debian 6 development server and noticed that a certain package named `tinyproxy` was upgraded. I have a particular interest in seeing precisely *what* changed in that package because modifying it to do some things that it currently does not do is on my list of things to do.

I know that I can fire up my browser, dig a little, find the changelog and see exactly what changed in the version I just went to, but then I wondered if there's a way I could ask `apt-get` or `dpkg` to show me a changelog if one was included.

Can I use either tool, or perhaps another to get a summary of what changed between versions of a package via the command line?

Comment: For every package there is a `/usr/share/doc/pkgname/changelog.Debian.gz` which lists the changes made by the Debian maintainer for the package. If the package has moved to a new upstream version, the upstream changelog should explain those changes, but its location is not perfectly predictable. Look in `/usr/share/doc/pkgname` for `changelog.gz` or similar. If you install `apt-listchanges` then all future upgrades with apt-get will show you the changelog automatically.

Comment: @Alan Curry: Is it possible the same using cmdline aptitude?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the package `apt-listchanges`. That will show you the Debian news and/or changelogs (its configurable) of the packages you're about to upgrade, and optionally ask for confirmation before upgrading. It can even open the changelogs in a browser, so you can click on links to bugs, etc.

Also, if you're using aptitude, press `C` when you have a package selected to see the changelog. As long as you have `libparse-debianchangelog-perl` installed, it'll even highlight which entries are new (aptitude recommends that Perl package).

Finally, you can read both the Debian and upstream changelogs in `/usr/share/doc/packagename/`.

Answer (score 6):

Nowdays the changelog command within apt-get, download and display a changelog for the given package:

> apt-get changelog tinyproxy

Answer (score 5):

The answer should be in `/usr/share/doc/tinyproxy/changelog.Debian.gz`. Use `zless` to view it.

Answer (score 0):

also note that changelogs are very high level and gloss over many details.  if you really need to know *"exactly what changed"*, you'll have to diff the source code between revisions.